# Nginx: hosting multiple WordPress sites as subdirectories returns 404 pages

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a root non-wordpress site that has 2 subdomains (/blog and /shop) as separate wordpress sites with separate databases. I’ve managed to set up separate mysql databases for them, and loading the root pages (i.e. /blog or /shop) and any page in their respective wp-admins also works.

However, loading any other page (e.g. /blog/article1 or /shop/product4) that isn’t the root /blog or /shop pages returns a 404 error page.

Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

Here is my .conf file in /etc/nginx/sites-available (also symlinked to /sites-enabled):

```
upstream wp-php-handler-four {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
server {
    listen 1224 default_server;
    listen [::]:1224 default_server;

    root /var/www/ecpn_sites;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /shop {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass wp-php-handler-four;
    }
}
```

I’ve tried changing `location ~ \.php$` to `location ~ /blog\.php$`, adding `index.php` inside the /blog and /shop blocks, and changing `?$args` to `?q=$uri&$args`, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to Nginx. Thanks.

Comment: The last parameter of your `try_files` statements should be `/blog/index.php?$args` and `/shop/index.php?$args`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `try_files` to:

```
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args /blog/index.php?$uri&$args ;
}

location /shop {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /shop/index.php?$args /shop/index.php?$uri&$args ;
}
```